# Running multiple grunt tasks

Tags: gruntjs

My Grunt file looks like this

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  shell: {
    runTest: {
      command: 'phpunit'
    },
    clear: {
      command: 'clear'
    },
    phpcs: {
      command: 'phpcs --standard=PSR2 ./app'
    },
    server: {
      command: 'php -S dev:1234 -t public'
    },
    selenium: {
      command: 'selenium'
    },
    chromedriver: {
      command: 'chromedriver'
    }
});
```

and I execute my tasks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('selenium', 'Selenium tasks', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    grunt.task.run('shell:server');
    grunt.task.run('shell:selenium');
    grunt.task.run('shell:chromedriver');
});
```

How can I run multiple tasks at the same time? With my current configuration, the grunt just finishes immediately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, things are even easier than you would think.

```
  grunt.registerTask('selenium', ['shell:server', 'shell:selenium', 'shell:chromedriver']);
```

Comment: The problem with this is it's procedural meaning it waits for the first command to finish before running the next.

Since they're all servers, I need them to run all at the same time.